# Spring batch read multiple tables from Database1 and write to database 2 tables

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am new to Spring batch. I have Spring framework with iBatis.
I want to read 3 tables from DB1 (let's say A,B and C) and want to store this to DB2 A, B and C.

Table A contains more than 100k rows. Reading and writing it to DB2 gives errors like "Disc space exceeded". As I am persisting the result into Object using getters and setters. I want to create batch for the same, but how should I proceed? I have gone through steps and all but not getting much idea.

Comment: I would suggest to use tasklet of Spring Batch, you don't need processor(I am guessing) and you just need to copy data from db1 to db2 (again assuming) I did something similar in one of my project but I used SELECT INSERT along with MsSQL database, check if something similar exists or not.

Comment: @BilboBaggins: Yes, You are right. I don't need oracle DB. I have defined tasklet as well. As I have mentioned I am getting error due to table A. I have oracle DB.

Comment: what is the error? ok got it. in this case you need to extend your disk space .. ;) ;)